# What is the difference between a rivet setter and rivet header?

Tags: tools, rivets

What is the difference between a [rivet setter](https://www.rennsteig.com/en/products/metalworking-tools/292-rivet-setters) and [rivet header](https://www.rennsteig.com/en/products/metalworking-tools/294-rivet-headers)? What sort of rivets are they used for? Do they require the use of an anvil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setter seats the rivet into the workpiece. The header rounds the rivet shank over to lock the workpiece in place.

Whether an anvil is required probably depends on the particular project.